# Raspbian OS supports for OPTEE

Tags: raspbian

I want to install raspbian OS on my raspberry PI 3 device, will it support TEE environment.If I want to run tee-supplicant and xtest, will they get executed .

Comment: What is OPTEE? What is the TEE environment?

Comment: Does https://optee.readthedocs.io/building/devices/rpi3.html help?